# How to click the allow button in chrome browser notification ? C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to read ebook online. The website is using Flash.
When I go to the website , I get a browser popup:
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46epu.png)

I've added this line to the driver initialization function but it's not working:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.notification", 1);
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Would it not just be easier to allow all for flash in the settings for chrome?

Comment: is this selenium? or something else?

Comment: @Steve selenium creates a new profile for each run.

Comment: @Daniel A. White yes, it is!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking on the **`Allow`** button every time we initiate the `Test Execution`, we can easily enable the `Flash` for all of the **`Chrome Browser Instances`** initiated by the **`WebDriver`** instance as follows:

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.plugins", 1);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
//crosscheck if the option switch is C# compatible (this is definately Java compatible)
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("<to_desired_page>");
```

Comment: After I set the variable as 2 the option turns `block` , but when I set the variable as 1 it still shows `ask` option.

Comment: How to turn the option `allow`?